# Does the Kill Zone perk stack with Guardian on a Specialist?

Tags: xcom-2

The Kill Zone ability says "Take a reaction shot against any enemy that moves or attacks within cone of fire" and the Guardian ability says "With every successful Overwatch shot, there is a 50% chance that another shot will be taken."

If Kill Zone does stack with Guardian, the descriptions lead me to believe that a Kill Zone/Guardian special could potentially deal a lot of damage to a whole pod of enemies.

Do these perks stack?

Comment: That could be seriously vicious.  I like the way you think!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yea you should get them to stack. Reaction shots are synonymous with overwatch shots.

Comment: thanks, I wasn't sure if reaction shots were the same as overwatch shots.

Comment: `Reaction shots are synonymous with overwatch shots.` Not entirely. If you suppress an enemy and they move (therefore taking a shot at them) also counts as a reaction shot.